# merge 2 jsons by an element using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, join, merge

I have this json result:

```
[
  {
    "nom_playlist": "bbbb",
    "countMedias": 2
  },
  {
    "nom_playlist": "ccc",
    "countMedias": 1
  },
  {
    "nom_playlist": "aaaa",
    "countMedias": 3
  },
  {
    "nom_playlist": "xxxx",
    "countMedias": 1
  },
  {
    "nom_playlist": "resttttttttt",
    "countMedias": 2
  }
]
```

I have this other json :

```
[ 
  {
    idPlayListe: 25,
    idUtilisateur: 11968,
    idMedia: 79,
    etat: 1,
    nomPlaylist: 'bbbb' 
  },
  { 
    idPlayListe: 32,
    idUtilisateur: 11968,
    idMedia: 79,
    etat: 0,
    nomPlaylist: 'ccc' 
   } 
]
```

I want to add the `etat` of the second json to the first json and join it by `nomPlaylist` and if `nomPlaylist` doesn't exist I want set `etat` by default to 0.

This is an example of how I want the results to be :

```
[
  {
    nom_playlist: 'bbbb',
    etat: 1,
    countMedias: 2
  },
  {
    nom_playlist: 'ccc',
    etat: 0,
    countMedias: 1
  },
  {
    nom_playlist: 'aaaa',
    etat: 0,
    countMedias: 3
  },
  {
    nom_playlist: 'xxxx',
    etat: 0,
    countMedias: 1
  },
  {
    nom_playlist: 'resttttttttt',
    etat: 0,
    countMedias: 2
  }
]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: can you tell us what you've tried

Comment: The simplest method would be to alter whatever DB query generates the JSON in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it, you could loop over the first array and then loop over the second and reassign `etat` if `nomPlaylist` is the same (forgive the variable naming, I don't know what this data is supposed to represent):

```js
const data = [
  { "nom_playlist": "bbbb", "countMedias": 2 },
  { "nom_playlist": "ccc", "countMedias": 1 },
  { "nom_playlist": "aaaa", "countMedias": 3 },
]
const otherData = [ 
  { etat: 1, nomPlaylist: 'bbbb' },
  { etat: 0, nomPlaylist: 'ccc' }
]

for ( const foo of data ) {
  let etat = 0;
  for ( const bar of otherData ) {
    if ( foo.nom_playlist === bar.nomPlaylist ) {
      etat = bar.etat;
      break;
    }
  }
  foo.etat = etat;
}
console.log( data );
```

Comment: This one is good although it unnecessarily loops over otherData each time data loops. Depending on otherdata size it can drastically decrease performance. It is way better to loop over otherData once and cache dict with data you need

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `map()` and `filter()`

```js
var arr1 = [{"nom_playlist": "bbbb","countMedias": 2},
            {"nom_playlist": "ccc","countMedias": 1},
            {"nom_playlist": "aaaa","countMedias": 3},
            {"nom_playlist": "xxxx","countMedias": 1},
            {"nom_playlist": "resttttttttt","countMedias": 2}];

var arr2 = [ {
    idPlayListe: 25,
    idUtilisateur: 11968,
    idMedia: 79,
    etat: 1,
    nomPlaylist: 'bbbb' 
  },{ 
    idPlayListe: 32,
    idUtilisateur: 11968,
    idMedia: 79,
    etat: 0,
    nomPlaylist: 'ccc' 
   } 
];
var res = arr1.map(i => {
  var etat = arr2.filter(j => j.nomPlaylist == i.nom_playlist);
  i.etat = etat.length > 0 ?  etat[0].etat : 0;
  return i;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

- Create a map of first array of objects using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
- Use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the first array and create a new object using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) using the map object (created above) to have the `etat` value from second array or defaults it to `0`.

```js
const data1 = [
  {"nom_playlist": "bbbb", "countMedias": 2},
  {"nom_playlist": "ccc", "countMedias": 1},
  {"nom_playlist": "aaaa", "countMedias": 3},
  {"nom_playlist": "xxxx", "countMedias": 1},
  {"nom_playlist": "resttttttttt", "countMedias": 2}
];

const data2 = [ 
  {idPlayListe: 25, idUtilisateur: 11968, idMedia: 79, etat: 1, nomPlaylist: 'bbbb'},
  {idPlayListe: 32, idUtilisateur: 11968, idMedia: 79, etat: 0, nomPlaylist: 'ccc'} 
];

const map = data2.reduce((r, c) => (r[c.nomPlaylist] = c, r), {});

const result = data1.map(
  o => Object.assign(
    {}, o, {etat: o.nom_playlist in map ? map[o.nom_playlist].etat : 0}
  )
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try such approach? Of course it needs some error checking and fallbacks.

```
const firstJson = ...;
const secondJson = ...;

const firstObject = JSON.parse(firstJson);
const secondObject = JSON.parse(secondJson);

const etatDict = secondObject.reduce((acc, cur) => acc[cur.nomPlaylist] = cur.etat, {});

for (const playlist of firstObject) {
    playlist.etat = etatDict[playlist.nom_playlist];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map` and `forEach` loop

```js
var a=[
  {
    "nom_playlist": "bbbb",
    "countMedias": 2
  },
  {
    "nom_playlist": "ccc",
    "countMedias": 1
  },
  {
    "nom_playlist": "aaaa",
    "countMedias": 3
  },
  {
    "nom_playlist": "xxxx",
    "countMedias": 1
  },
  {
    "nom_playlist": "resttttttttt",
    "countMedias": 2
  }
]


var b=[ 
  {
    idPlayListe: 25,
    idUtilisateur: 11968,
    idMedia: 79,
    etat: 1,
    nomPlaylist: 'bbbb' 
  },
  { 
    idPlayListe: 32,
    idUtilisateur: 11968,
    idMedia: 79,
    etat: 0,
    nomPlaylist: 'ccc' 
   } 
]
console.log(a.map(function(e){
b.forEach(function(k){
k.nomPlaylist==e.nom_playlist?e.etat=k.etat:false
})
if(!e.hasOwnProperty('etat'))
e.etat=0;
return e;
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    // first array of objects  
    var firstJson = [
            {
              "nom_playlist": "bbbb",
              "countMedias": 2
            },
            {
              "nom_playlist": "ccc",
              "countMedias": 1
            },
            {
              "nom_playlist": "aaaa",
              "countMedias": 3
            },
            {
              "nom_playlist": "xxxx",
              "countMedias": 1
            },
            {
              "nom_playlist": "resttttttttt",
              "countMedias": 2
            }
        ];
          
        // second array of objects 
        var secondJson = [
            {
              nom_playlist: 'bbbb',
              etat: 1,
              countMedias: 2
            },
            {
              nom_playlist: 'ccc',
              etat: 0,
              countMedias: 1
            },
            {
              nom_playlist: 'aaaa',
              etat: 0,
              countMedias: 3
            },
            {
              nom_playlist: 'xxxx',
              etat: 0,
              countMedias: 1
            },
            {
              nom_playlist: 'resttttttttt',
              etat: 0,
              countMedias: 2
            }
        ];
       // Generating updated array using firstJson and secondJson arryas
       
        var mergedJson = firstJson.map(item => {    
            secondJson.forEach(obj => {
                if (item.nom_playlist === obj.nomPlaylist) {
                    item["etat"] = obj.etat;
                }                
            });
            if(!item["etat"]) {
                item["etat"] = 0;
            }
            return item;
        });
        console.log(mergedJson);
```